# C# postfix and prefix increment/decrement overloading difference

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Most sources says that overloading ++ and -- operators in c# results overloading both, postfix and prefix at once. But it looks like their behaviour is still different.

```
class Counter
{
    public Counter(int v = 0)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public Counter(Counter c)
    {
        v = c.v;
    }
    public int GetValue() { return v; }
    public static Counter operator ++(Counter c)
    {
        c.v++;
        return new Counter(c);
    }
    private int v;
}


class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Counter c1 = new Counter(1);

        Counter c2 = c1++;

        Counter c3 = ++c1;

        c3++;

        System.Console.WriteLine("c1 = {0}", c1.GetValue());
        System.Console.WriteLine("c2 = {0}", c2.GetValue());
        System.Console.WriteLine("c3 = {0}", c3.GetValue());
    }
}
```

Wonderfully, although overloaded `operator ++` returns copy of the original class, in this example `c1` and `c3` becomes references to the same object, while `c2` points to different one (`c1=4, c2=2, c3=4` here). Changing `Counter c3 = ++c1;` to `Counter c3 = c1++;` outputs `c1=3, c2=2, c3=4`.

So, what is the exact difference between postfix and prefix increment/decrement and how it affects overloading? Are these operators acts same way for classes and for primitive types?

Comment: There's a bug in your `operator ++`: you're not only returning an object for the incremented value, but modify the object to which the operator is applied as well. It should be: `public static Counter operator ++(Counter c) { return new Counter(c.v + 1); }`

Comment: But this is what increment supposed to do, `i++` have to change value of `i`, haven't it?

Comment: No. `i++` remembers the value of the variable `i` (let's call it `i_old`), calculates the value `i+1` (let's call it `i_new`), stores the value `i_new` in the variable `i`, and returns the value `i_old`.

Comment: `i++` should act this way, but `++i` other way... I suppose c# unlike c++ do something itself when calling these operators but I could not catch it. Anyway, this example shows that although c# allows overload only one method for `operator ++`, it acts in different way for increment and decrement calling.

Comment: `++i` remembers the value of the variable `i` (`i_old`), calculates the value `i+1` (`i_new`), stores the value `i_new` in the variable `i`, and returns the value `i_new`. The `operator ++(x)` method is what calculates `i+1`; all the other steps are taken care of by the C# compiler. So it's actually pretty consistent.

Comment: Why `++i` requires `i_old` this case? Could you explain this as an answer or post reference to documentation? What is correct way to overload increment/decrement operators after all and why? Are `i_old` and `i_new` references or copies of objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the wrong way to implement increment and decrement in C#.  You will get crazy results if you do it wrong; you did it wrong, you got crazy results, so the system works. :-)

Coincidentally I wrote an article about this very subject last week:

http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/25/bug-guys-meets-math-from-scratch/

As commenter dtb points out, the correct implementation is:

```
    public static Counter operator ++(Counter c)
    {
        return new Counter(c.v + 1);
    }
```

In C# the increment operator **must not mutate its argument**. Rather it must only compute the incremented value and return it, without producing any side effects. The side effect of mutating the variable will be handled by the compiler.

With this correct implementation your program now goes like this:

```
    Counter c1 = new Counter(1);
```

Call the object that c1 refers to right now `W`. `W.v` is 1.

```
    Counter c2 = c1++;
```

This has the semantics of:

```
temp = c1
c1 = operator++(c1) // create object X, set X.v to 2
c2 = temp
```

So `c1` now refers to `X`, and `c2` refers to `W`.  `W.v` is 1 and `X.v` is 2.

```
    Counter c3 = ++c1;
```

This has the semantics of

```
temp = operator++(c1) // Create object Y, set Y.v to 3
c1 = temp
c3 = temp
```

So c1 and c3 now both refer to object `Y`, and `Y.v` is 3.

```
    c3++;
```

This has the semantics of

```
c3 = operator++(c3) // Create object Z, set Z.v to 4
```

So when the smoke all clears:

```
c1.v = 3 (Y)
c2.v = 1 (W)
c3.v = 4 (Z)
```

and `X` is orphaned.

This should give exactly the same results as if you'd had `c1`, `c2` and `c3` as normal integers.

Comment: It's too bad in some ways that the `operator` *declaration* uses `++` and `--` as the names of the "plus one" and "minus one" operations; I wonder if it would have been more or less confusing if there were an otherwise-invalid token sequence [e.g. `+%`] which represented the value which the operator overload computes, so `X=Y+%` would set `X` to the value which would be computed by `++Y`, but without the write-back to `Y`.  If such an operator existed, the relations among the `+%` overload and the the prefix/postfix operators would be more intuitive than they are with the overload called `++`.

Comment: @supercat: If such an operator existed, it would be less intuitive to the user that it has to be used to overload ++ and --. I do agree with what you're saying, though, about it not being intuitive that you're not supposed to mutate the object when you overload ++ and --. Either way, there's some non-intuitiveness in there.

Comment: @RobH: I don't see how it would be overly less intuitive than the fact that other than the special compiler-generated "overload" for events, the `+=` and `-=` operators are overloaded by overloading `+` and `-` respectively, a design I don't particularly like btw, especially with types like `Delegate` which are supposed to behave like values.  If `evt` is an auto-event, the statement `evt += someDelegate` will add `someDelegate` to `evt` atomically; it is *not* equivalent to `evt = evt + someDelegate;`.  Unfortunately, there's no way to overload operators to make other delegates do that.

Comment: @supercat: I don't mind at all that += is implemented by calling +, but I do find it somewhat odd that += on an event means "call the event add accessor". I think if the C#/CLR team had to do it all over again with the benefit of what we know now, events would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @EricLippert: There isn't much I like about .NET events, but my point about `+=` is that semantically it sometimes makes sense for the operator to behave as an in-place operation on something (e.g. via an `Interlocked`-guarded update loop), rather than as a read followed by a later write.  This distinction would be most useful if properties could return types which were flagged as "ephemeral" (but could allow implicit conversion to ordinary types), such that `myThing.someProperty += something;` could result in `myThing` being told to append `something`, without having to...

Comment: ...read out all the data associated with `someProperty`, modify it, and write it all back.  If only one semantically-meaningful reference exists to an object, updating it in-place is semantically equivalent to making a new altered version, but may often be much faster.