# Prefix and Postfix operator overloading in C#

Tags: c#, oop, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

The following code has a runtime issue with unexpected references made by assignment of postfix/prefix increment statement as shown in the code bellow. Also can anyone please suggest me with a way to treat objects as value types in C# as suggested bellow if any?

I believe that the code is well documented with comments clarifying each important state. Feel free to ask any questions regarding clarification of code or the problem at hand.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Test {

    public int x;

    public Test(int x) { this.x=x; }    
    public Test() { x=0; }

    static public Test operator++(Test obj) {
        return new Test(obj.x+1);
    }   
}

 // In implementing module
 // Prefix/Postfix operator test for inbuilt (scalar) datatype 'int'
 int x=2;
 int y=++x; // 'y' and 'x' now both have value '3'
 Console.WriteLine(x++); // Displays '3'
 Console.WriteLine(++x); // Displays '5'
 Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x,y)); // Displays 'False'


 // Prefix/Postfix operator test of class type 'Test'
 Test obj=new Test();
 obj.x=1;
 Console.WriteLine(obj++); // Must have displayed '1', displays the object type (Test.Test)
 Console.WriteLine(++obj); // Must have displayed '3', again displays the object type (Test.Test)
 Console.WriteLine(obj.x); // Displays '3' (as expected)

 Test obj2=++obj; // Must have the value '4' and must NOT be the reference of obj
 // Alternative solution to the above statement can be : 'Test obj2=new Test(++obj);' but isn't there a way to create a new value type in C# by the above statement ??!! (In C++, it can be acheived by overloading the '=' operator but C# doesn't allow it)
 Console.WriteLine(obj2.x); // Displays '4' (as expected)
 Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(obj,obj2)); // Must display 'False' but displays 'True' showing that 'obj2' is the reference of 'obj'
```

Comment: Well yes, you haven't overridden `ToString()`. At that point, half of your objections go away. It would really help if you'd write a [mcve] demonstrating a *single* issue.

Comment: @user3185569: I removed that bit of the comment. It looks to me like the part about `obj` and `obj2` should be okay... It doesn't help that there are so many conflated issues here.

Comment: Actually no, I see what's wrong with the `Test obj2=++obj` part. Will add an answer for that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Does that means we need to override the 'ToString()' method to treat classes as value types? Like if we want the command 'Console.WriteLine(obj);' to display the value of the required field.

Comment: @hecate No, but you can just replace it with `Console.WriteLine(obj++.x);` to print the value

Comment: It's got nothing to do with treating it as a value type. It's got everything to do with customizing how an instance is converted to a string when you call `Console.WriteLine(obj)`... basically that will call `obj.ToString()` (if `obj` is non-null).

Comment: @user3185569 Hey I know about 'Console.WriteLine(obj++.x);'; I just want my code to treat the class object as value types (like in C++)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup, I agree with you and it solves the issue at hand. Thanks. Well do you have any idea to resolve the reference issue ? :)

Comment: @hecate: I've added an answer - basically the problem is with your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to adjust a type that is declared as `class` to behave as a `struct`. This doesn't make any sense for me. If you change `class Test` to `struct Test`, remove the parameterless constructor and override the `.ToString` method, all the problems are gone.

First, You're creating a new instance of Test each time you increment (Post or Pre). So when you hit this line:

```
Test obj2 = ++obj;
```

As if you're writing:

```
obj = new Test(obj.x + 1);
Test obj2 = obj;
```

Second and as for the printing issue, just override the ToString:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return x.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Well then how can I have them not have the same reference ? Thanks for reply.

Comment: @hecate Then there is no reason in having `Test` as a class if you don't want it to be treated by reference. Convert it to a `Struct` then. Doing that you'll have Copy by Value Semantics and this issue is gone.

Comment: Thanks. Converting the 'Test' class to a structure helped. Thanks again :)

Comment: @hecate I updated the answer with the steps, you need to remove the parameterless constructor also because it doesn't make any sense for value-types.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you've misunderstood how this line works:

```
Test obj2 = ++obj;
```

If you think of using your operator as a method, that's like saying:

```
obj = Test.operator++(obj);
obj2 = obj;
```

So yes, you end up with `obj` and `obj2` being the same reference. The result of `++obj` is the value of `obj` *after* applying the `++` operator, but that `++` operator affects the value of `obj` too.

If you use

```
Test obj2 = obj++;
```

then that's equivalent to:

```
Test tmp = obj;
obj = Test.operator++(obj);
obj2 = tmp;
```

At that point, the value of `obj2` will refer to the original object, and the vlaue of `obj` will refer to the newly-created object with a higher `x` value.

The rest of your question around the result of `Console.WriteLine` is really because you haven't overridden `ToString()`.

Comment: Well then how can I have them not have the same reference ? Thanks for reply.

Comment: @hecate: You can't. Look at what `Test obj2 = ++obj;` means - the last part of it is `obj2 = obj;`. How would you expect that to give different references? Note that if `Test` is immutable, it shouldn't matter. (As noted elsewhere, you can make `Test` a struct, but then there are no references anywhere...)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136616/c-sharp-postfix-and-prefix-increment-decrement-overloading-difference) you provided to the deleted answer, then:

```
Test obj2 = ++obj;
```

Is translated to

```
temp = operator++(obj);
obj = temp;
obj2 = temp;
```

Which means they have the same reference.

Comment: Well then how can I have them not have the same reference ? Thanks for reply.

Comment: You can't if you just want to use the ++ operator. Only one instance is created for the `increased` version.